# Mounting drives and Udev - Udev does not mount drives but executes other aspects of the script

Tags: mount, udev

I want to hot plug an external hard drive, have it mount and automatically run the Unison File Synchronizer.

I have made a udev rule called `/etc/udev/rules.d/100-sync.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="wxyz", ATTRS{idProduct}=="wxyz", RUN+="/home/william/sync.sh"
```

It triggers this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /media/william/Backup
mount -U <my_drives_uuid> /media/william/Backup
su william -c 'notify-send "Unison" "Starting Sync"'
su william -c 'unison Desktop_Ext_local_connection.prf -silent > /home/william/unison_errors.log'
su william -c 'notify-send "Unison" "Finished Sync"'
umount /media/william/Backup
rmdir /media/william/Backup
```

Running the script from a root shell works as expected, however when it is triggered by udev, the drive does not mount. (I still get system notifications and directory creation/destruction)

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330094/udev-rule-to-mount-disk-does-not-work), I think it doesn't work because udev uses a different namespace. I've tried creating a file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service` with the contents

```
[Service]
MountFlags=shared *(and alternatively PrivateMounts=no)*
```

However this does not change the behaviour - it still doesn't mount. (yes I restarted the daemon)

How can I get the drive to mount using udev?

After my script is done, Ubuntu automatically mounts the drive. Is there a work around which lets Ubuntu mount the drive before udev runs my script?

I cannot see any udev rule which Ubuntu uses to mount the drive, the contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d` are just

```
100-sync.rules  70-snap.snapd.rules  70-snap.snap-store.rules
```

So how is Ubuntu mounting the drive after my script is done, and how can I change the order so that they are mounted first?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, the same issue occurs on my laptop running 21.04

Comment: I've found a work around where I have 2 scripts. The first script starts the second using `nohup` then exits, allowing Ubuntu to mount the drive. The second waits 10 seconds to allow time for the mount then runs Unison. I do not find this work around very satisfying.

Comment: I commented a little to soon without fully testing... It doesn't work, but scheduling the second script does. e.g. `at now + 1 minute -f sync2.sh`

Comment: Yeah, Scheduling (pulling) is one way to go.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, all udev scripts that include FS mounting are old few years ago. I believe it had been changed around the time `systemd` emerged.

Here is a reference note from **udev_237 - [man udev](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html)  (Ubuntu_18.04)**

> *`RUN{type}`*
>
>   ︙
>
> Note that running programs that access the network or
> mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules,
> due to the default sandbox that is enforced on
> systemd-udevd.service.

Better to go with solutions that use libs like udev, udisks, ... Or an external script that keep watching for that device.

BTW, `100-` is too early even for other applications (udev rules files are processed in lexical order), wise to change it into a high 2 digit number. If you want last use `99-`